# Creating a jQuery UI sortable in an iframe

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable

On a page I have an iframe. In this iframe is a collection of items that I need to be sortable. All of the Javascript is being run on the parent page. I can access the list in the iframe document and create the sortable by using context:

```
var ifrDoc = $( '#iframe' ).contents();

$( '.sortable', ifrDoc ).sortable( { cursor: 'move' } );
```

However, when trying to actually sort the items, I'm getting some aberrant behavior. As soon as an item is clicked on, the target of the script changes to the outer document. If you move the mouse off of the iframe, you can move the item around and drop it back by clicking, but you can not interact with it within the iframe.

Example: http://robertadamray.com/sortable-test.html

So, is there a way to achieve what I want to do - preferably without having to go hacking around in jQuery UI code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dynamically add jQuery and jQuery UI to the iframe ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/Ht4Zc/16/)):

```
$('iframe')
    .load(function() {
        var win = this.contentWindow,
            doc = win.document,
            body = doc.body,
            jQueryLoaded = false,
            jQuery;

        function loadJQueryUI() {
            body.removeChild(jQuery);
            jQuery = null;

            win.jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js',
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: true,
                success: function () {
                    win.jQuery('.sortable').sortable({ cursor: 'move' });
                }
            });
        }

        jQuery = doc.createElement('script');

        // based on https://gist.github.com/getify/603980
        jQuery.onload = jQuery.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ((jQuery.readyState && jQuery.readyState !== 'complete' && jQuery.readyState !== 'loaded') || jQueryLoaded) {
                return false;
            }
            jQuery.onload = jQuery.onreadystatechange = null;
            jQueryLoaded = true;
            loadJQueryUI();
        };

        jQuery.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
        body.appendChild(jQuery);
    })
    .prop('src', 'iframe-test.html');
```

​
**Update:** [Andrew Ingram is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224341/311572) that jQuery UI holds and uses references to `window` and `document` for the page to which jQuery UI was loaded. By loading jQuery / jQuery UI into the iframe, it has the correct references (for the iframe, rather than the outer document) and works as expected.

---

**Update 2:** The original code snippet had a subtle issue: the execution order of dynamic script tags isn't guaranteed. I've updated it so that jQuery UI is loaded after jQuery is ready.

I also incorporated getify's code to [load LABjs dynamically](https://gist.github.com/getify/603980), so that no polling is necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a clean enough workaround to me. Could you add an explanation, or a link to one, of why this fixes the issue?

Comment: "This seems like a clean enough workaround to me.". Really? This is straight up polling. It's a horrible solution for production. There *has* to be a better way than this.

Comment: @kamelkev The demo code is only there to illustrate the answer (load jQuery and jQuery UI into the iframe); there is no guarantee of production-readiness. Still, I've updated the answer so that it does not use polling.

Answer (score 5):

Having played with their javascript a bit, Campaign Monitor solves this by basically having a custom version of jQuery UI. They've modified ui.mouse and ui.sortable to replace references to document and window with code that gets the document and window for the element in question. `document` becomes `this.element[0].ownerDocument`

and they have a custom jQuery function called window() which lets them replace `window` with `this.element.window()` or similar.

Comment: That's how we're handling it now. I've basically written a plugin that extends the necessary functions with code that will work. This is hacky and, I fear, specific to our situation. Can you provide a link to a resource that would allow others with this problem to solve it?

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you post the link for the custom jQuery file?

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you post a link for this one, I think ill go with this approach. or a guide perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why your code isn't working. Looks like it should be.

That said, here are two alternative ways to implement this feature:

1. **If you can modify the iframe**

   Move your JavaScript from the parent document into `iframe-test.html`. This may be the cleanest way because it couples the JavaScript with the elements its actually executing on.

   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3287783/snippets/rarayiframe/sortable-test.html
2. **If you only control the parent document**
   Use the jQuery .load() method to fetch the content instead of an HTML iframe.
   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3287783/snippets/rarayiframe2/sortable-test.html

Comment: Of course, but that's not my use case. I control only the parent document.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer with a 2nd way to implement this, which may work for you, even if it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's a really interesting point, and something I hadn't thought of. I don't know if it will work for the more complex system that spawned my question, but I'll definitely be giving it a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading jQuery and jQueryUI inside the iFrame and evaluating jQueryUI interactions both in parent and child - you can simply bubble the mouse events to the parent's document:

```
var ifrDoc = $( '#iframe' ).contents();

$('.sortable', ifrDoc).on('mousemove mouseup', function (event) {
    $(parent.document).trigger(event);
});
```

This way you can evaluate all your Javascript on the parent's document context.