# Sorting UL Listing Within the TinyMCE Visual Editor in Wordpress

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable, wordpress

I am trying to use jQuery sortable within the TinyMCE Visual Editor in Wordpress.  I have had some success in that I can get a UL list to sort, but only if I drag the mouse OUTSIDE of the actual editor.  You can see what I mean with this short 1 minute screencast video:  http://screencast.com/t/1FNMvLw3Y

Here is the code I am using to run this:

```
    (function() {
   tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.tinyMceSort', {
      init : function(ed, url) {
         ed.addButton('tinyMceSort', {
            title : 'TinyMCE Sort',
            image : url+'/tiny_sort.png',
            onclick : function() {
                 ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '\
                    <ul id="list">\
                      <li>One</li>\
                      <li>Two</li>\
                      <li>Three</li>\
                      <li>Four</li>\
                      <li>Five</li>\
                    </ul>\
                ');
              }
          });

        ed.onVisualAid.add(function(ed, e, s) {
          console.debug('onVisualAid event: ' + ed.id + ", State: " + s);
           // jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('#move').sortable({ containment: '#move' });
            jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('#list').sortable({ containment : 'parent', tolerance : 'pointer', cursor : 'move'}).css({'width' : '200px', 'padding' : '10px', 'list-style' : 'none', 'background-color' : '#333'});
            jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('li').css({'background-color' : 'grey', 'margin': '10px', 'padding': '10px'});
            jQuery('.wrap').sortable();
      });


    ed.plugins.wordpress._showButtons(target, 'tinyMceSort');

          }
      });
    },

    createControl : function(n, cm) {
      return null;
    },

    getInfo : function() {
      return {
        longname : "TinyMCE Sort",
        author : '',
        authorurl : '',
        infourl : '',
        version : ""
      };
    },
  });
   tinymce.PluginManager.add('tinyMceSort', tinymce.plugins.tinyMceSort);
})();
```

What I would like to know is what do I have do in order to sort the list WITHOUT having to move the mouse outside of the TinyMCE Editor area.

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce uses an iframe. I guess the necessary code is not available in the tinymce iframe.
In order to load the javascript files using the tinymce [script loader](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aclass.tinymce.dom.ScriptLoader)for the iframe too you may use onInit of tinymce this

```
// Load a script from a specific URL using the global script loader
tinymce.ScriptLoader.load('somescript.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, but this doesn't seem to help.  I did a further search and found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11240770/1653801) which seems that it might also help, but alas I can't get that answer to work outside of jsfiddler.  Any other ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I've made some progress - I tried a different sorting plugin (HTML5 Sortable -- https://github.com/farhadi/html5sortable).  It works!  However, it adds draggable='true' and style="display: list-item;" directly to the li tags that I'm dragging which I do NOT want, as I don't want those to get published to the frontend (this is, after all, in the wordpress visual editor).  So, I'm looking for other alternatives - any ideas?  Alternatively, any way to fix jquery ui?

Comment: beware of jquery ui - i do not touch that if possible

Comment: Interesting - why is that, if I may ask (I know it's a bit off topic, but not 100% since I do have to choose a solution).  Can you perhaps point me to an article or something letting me know it's shortcomings?

Comment: no, problem we had is to make jQuery UI work with other js libraries (i guess our use case was a bit specific, jQuery should work fine in most cases)